# Aggregate list of values into slots using python

Tags: python

I am trying to aggregate a list of values into defined intervals.

I have below string which represents `units: timestamp`

```
2:0,1: 9,5:10,2:12,4:19,5:35
```

which implies the below info:

```
units: 2, timestamp: 0
units: 1, timestamp: 9
units: 5, timestamp: 10
units: 2, timestamp: 12
units: 4, timestamp: 19
units: 5, timestamp: 35
```

I am trying to calculate the max value in intervals of `10`

Here is my solution so far:

```py
units_to_parse = '2:0,1:9,5:10,2:12,4:19,5:35'

def parse_units(units_to_parse):
    units_to_parse = units_to_parse.split(',')
    
    units = []
    cur_timestamp = 0
    
    for pair in units_to_parse:
        unit = pair.split(':')[0]
        timestamp = int(pair.split(':')[1])
        if timestamp < cur_timestamp + 10:
            units.append(unit)
        elif timestamp >= cur_timestamp + 10:
            print(f"{cur_timestamp}, {max(units)}")
            units = [unit]
            cur_timestamp = cur_timestamp + 10
      
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parse_units( units_to_parse)
```

I am trying to fill in the missing slots with the previous slot max value. Something like this:

```
{timeslot: maxvalue}
{0: 2} {10: 5} {20: 5} {30: 5}
```

any good way to fill missing slot info here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you need to find the `max timestamp` and `min timestamp`. And form a key value dictionary based on that timestamp.

##### Note that key is always timestamp as it should be unique in dictionary

```py
units_to_parse = '2:0,1:9,5:10,2:12,4:19,5:35,7:38,0:40,6:55,9:75'
def parse_units(units_to_parse):
    units_to_parse = units_to_parse.split(',')
    
    max_timestamp = max([int(a.split(':')[1]) for a in units_to_parse])
    max_timestamp = max_timestamp - (max_timestamp%10)
    
    min_timestamp = min([int(a.split(':')[1]) for a in units_to_parse])
    min_timestamp = min_timestamp - (min_timestamp%10)
    
    time_val  = {int(a.split(':')[1]):int(a.split(':')[0]) for a in units_to_parse} #form a dictionary where key should be timestamp
    temp_val = {}
    for t in range(min_timestamp, max_timestamp+1, 10):
        try:
            t_range = list(range(t, t+10))
            v_range = [v for k,v in time_val.items() if k in t_range]
            print(t, max(v_range))
            temp_val[t] = max(v_range)
        except:  #if key is not found
            print(t, list(temp_val.values())[-1])
            temp_val[t] = list(temp_val.values())[-1]
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parse_units(units_to_parse)
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, the above solution is not getting the max value for particular slot. For example if we have the input as `''2:0,1:9,5:10,2:12,4:19,5:35, 7:38"` we are getting output as :

0 2
10 5
20 5
30 5
But the intended output is :
0 2
10 5
20 5
30 7

Comment: here the slot `30` has timestamps (35, 38) and their values (5, 7) so the max value of slot(30) would be `7`

Comment: so slot 30 ranges from 30-40 or 20-30? I did not got your question clearly

Comment: sorry, I could have made my question more clear. Slot 30 would have values of timestamps [30-40) 
30 included, till 39 but not 40

Comment: @CodingBabai just updated the answer, check it